# Why is it so slow to read ES on Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I'm trying to read ElasticSearch by using the Spark-ES API provided by the ES. I think spark can make the query faster. But it's really slow, even much slower than using the ES rest API.

I tested the speed of the rest API and the spark API, and find that the spark API is much slower.

here is my spark configuration:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("readEs")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
                .set("es.nodes", "55.13.9.136")
                .set("es.port", "9200")
                .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true");

SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
```

here is the query part:

```
JavaRDD<Map<String, Object>> searchRdd = esRDD(jsc, "20190904", o.toJSONString()).values();

for(Map<String,Object> item:searchRdd.collect()){
                    item.forEach((key,value)->{
                        System.out.println("search key:"+key+", search value: "+ value);
                    });
```

here is how I use the es rest API:

```
client = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("55.13.9.136",9200,"http")).build();
entity = new NStringEntity(o.toJSONString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = client.performRequest("GET","/20190904/_search",params,entity);
responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONObject jsonObject = JSON.parseObject(responseBody);
System.out.println("result: "+jsonObject.get("hits"));
```

I'm searching the data by timestamp, the interval is 10000ms, through about 30 minutes, it loops 180 times. The spark api takes about 36000ms and the es rest api takes about 2500ms. And I found that if I delete the "searchRDD.collect()" or "searchRDD.count()" line, the spark api takes about 500ms. I dont't know if the query ran. If it did run, if I can't use the searchRDD method, how can I get the data? Thanks.

Comment: You made a correct observation: if you remove `.count()` or `.collect()` Spark will only prepare for execution, it will not execute queries. May I ask you how big is the result set of the query? How many items the `searchRDD` is supposed to have?

Comment: My purpose is to finish a lot of query in the same index. And I found i made a mistake, I used ```RDD.collect()``` every time when I get a new query, which makse it really slow because I query all data every time.Now i use ```RDD.collect()``` to get all data, and store data to memory, which perfomes much better. But i think it's much better because i store the data to the memory. Do you know how to optimize the queries through Spark?I didn't think I made good use of Spark.And the data is not big, it's about 50MB~2GB. Thanks!

Comment: Good to see that you are making progress with your issue! How many results from each query do you need to download? Are they less than 10k or more than that?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev I downloaded 2MB of data at a time and made 720 queries against it locally.As it turns out, the Spark+ES scheme is slower than the ES scheme when I download the same amount of data and run the same number of queries locally.My guess is that (1) the total amount of data in the query is small.(2) the calculation in memory is too simple.For both of these reasons, Spark's strengths have not been exploited.Right?

Comment: I think when you have just 2MB of data per query, and 720 queries, Spark adds a lot of overhead, which is probably bigger than any performance gain. As far as I understand es-hadoop lib will do [`scroll`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll) queries which are slower than normal (paginated) searches. Spark + es-hadoop work best for downloading large collections of data, say, entire index.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be easier to have a script on client side that does N queries in parallel; I am afraid I can't provide any better idea. Hope you will find a solution!

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev Your advice gave me a lot of inspiration. Thank you very much.